# VBA type mismatch on DO WHILE NOT

Tags: vba, excel, do-while, type-mismatch

I've got o problem with my macro:

```
Dim nr_kol As Integer
nr_kol = ActiveCell.Column
Worksheets("dane").Range("I1").Copy
Worksheets("dystr hist").Range("a1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -nr_kol + 1) = ""
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -nr_kol + 1).Text, Worksheets("temp2").Range("B:I"), 8, False)
Loop
```

It should work like this: it takes week number from "dane" sheet and paste it in "dystr hist" sheet in first free cell in first row. Then we have vlookup for items, until the list is finished.
It worked for previous sheet, but in this particular place it crashes with type mismatch. Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Perhaps you have an error value in one of the cells.

Comment: Have you tried Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -nr_kol + 1))

Comment: Side Note: (1) You should [avoid using Select and Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate). (2) Always use `Long` instead of `Integer` (read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the explanation why that you asked for:

The issue is you select range A1 with

```
Worksheets("dystr hist").Range("a1").Select 
'here you do some copy which doesn't change cell selection of A1
```

and next you try to move a probably negative column value in

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -nr_kol + 1)
```

where `-nr_kol + 1` is negative for `nr_kol > 1`. This doesn't work because A1 is the most top most left cell in the sheet and you just can't move left.

---

Solution:

- Avoid using `ActiveCell`
- Avoid using `Select`
- Fully qualify your Cells/Ranges with worksheets
- [Use `Long` instead of `Integer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613)

Answer (score 0):

What is `-nr_kol` in
`Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -nr_kol + 1) = ""`

Probably you want to write
`Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, (nr_kol + 1) *-1) = ""`

In general, probably you may try something like this:

```
Dim nr_kol As long
nr_kol = ActiveCell.Column
Worksheets("dane").Range("I1").Copy
Worksheets("dystr hist").Range("a1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).select
Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -nr_kol + 1) = ""
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -nr_kol + 1).Text, Worksheets("temp2").Range("B:I"), 8, False)
Loop
```

The difference is in the change of the `ActiveCell` with the following code:
    `ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).select`

Comment: `nr_kol + 1 *-1` is the same as `nr_kol -1` isn't it?

Comment: @Peh - I am still sleepy.

Comment: Still won't work. Selected cell is A1 (from 2 lines above in his code) and you try to move in negative direction. Can't work (see my answer).

Comment: @Peh - he was probably meaning that the active cell is the last cell in the selection... I guess...

Comment: yes, hard to tell without any information of the OP. Or he thinks the ActiveCell of the beginning before any macro ran is still selected. Nevertheless the code needs some improvement.